# Как перезагрузить карту google в центре layout primefaces при изменении размера окна браузера

Tags: javascript, primefaces

Использую primefaces. В центеральном layout располагается карта Google.

```
<p:layoutUnit position="center" resizable="false" closable="false" collapsible="false" collapsed="false" styleClass="ui-layout-center" >

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true|false"
    type="text/javascript"/>


<h:form>
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" life="4000" />
    <p:gmap id ="map" center="#{mapBean.latCenter}, #{mapBean.lonCenter}" zoom="#{mapBean.zoomLevel}" type="ROADMAP"
        style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%" model="#{mapBean.model}" styleClass = "mapClass" widgetVar="gmap">
        <p:ajax event="stateChange" listener="#{mapBean.onStateChange}"
            update="messages, map" fixBounds="false"/>
    </p:gmap>
```

При изменении размеров окна карта полностью не восстанавливается. При уменьшении а потом при увеличении остается только кусок карты в маленьком окне.
Попробовал применить скрипт

```
</p:layout>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onresize = function(event) {
        var gmap = PF('gmap').getMap();;
        var height = $(window).height() - 300 - 200;
         var width = $(window).width()  - 50 - 100;     
         gmap.height = height;
         gmap.width = width;
    } 

 </script>
```

Но это проблему не решило. Функция GoogleApi `google.maps.event.trigger(gmap, "resize");` также не работает. Как решить данную проблему ?